# Find Accounts without Attachments

Tags: apex, attachment, csv

In a CSv file  I have a list of AccountId's. I am trying to determine the best way to find if these Accounts have an Attachment.

One Approach that come to  mind is this -

1. Write an Apex script to get all Accounts that has attachment.
2. Export this list of AccountID's to csv
3. Do a vlook between the list in #2 above and the list I have.

Am i on the right path, is there a better approach?

Thank You !!

Comment: Just export both tables and do the manipulation in Excel, or even Access. It's not too difficult.

Comment: how many rows of accountIds?

Comment: I ended up as suggested by @sfdxfox, exported both tables and did manipulation in excel.